# msqli 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax jfactor

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've report error:

> 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM WHERE = '751'' at line 2 SQL=SELECT FROM WHERE = '751';

**Code:**

```
public static function tre()
{   
    $risultato = modUno::due(); 
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "
    SELECT ".$db->nameQuote('avatar')."
    FROM ".$db->nameQuote('#__comprofiler')."
    WHERE ".$db->nameQuote('id')." = ".$db->quote($risultato).";";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->loadResult();        
}
```

Comment: what is this ` WHERE = '751';` ??

Comment: Try to use backticks for table name,that # is dubious.

Comment: 751 is the value of $risultato

Answer (score 0):

Your `$db->nameQuote('avatar')`, `$db->nameQuote('#__comprofiler')`, `$db->nameQuote('id')` are  underfined.

There are several problems in the `SELECT FROM WHERE = '751';`

- missing column name[s] after `SELECT`
- missing tablename after `FROM`
- missing column name after `WHERE`

Try to check it before you passing it to the query.

Comment: How can you say that ?

Answer (score -1):

The Problem is

```
WHERE ".$db->nameQuote('id')." = ".$db->quote($risultato).";
```

here..

Please verify that you table has a column name id.. I think you column id has some other name..

Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: try to use

public static function tre()
{   
    $risultato = modUno::due(); 
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "
    SELECT avatar
    FROM #__comprofiler
    WHERE id = ".$db->quote($risultato);
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->loadResult();        
}